# What is causing my logs to flood with low-speed USB device notices?

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse, devices, syslog

I have a box running Ubuntu 14.04 with all patches installed. Suddenly about a week ago my logs started getting flooded with hundreds of messages a minute that look like the following:

```
Jun 18 11:28:49 Serv kernel: [778682.205315] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:49 Serv kernel: [778682.461172] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 25 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:49 Serv kernel: [778682.717029] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 26 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:50 Serv kernel: [778682.972886] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 27 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:50 Serv kernel: [778683.228750] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:50 Serv kernel: [778683.484602] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:51 Serv kernel: [778683.740444] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 30 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:51 Serv kernel: [778683.996318] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:51 Serv kernel: [778684.252176] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 32 using ehci-pci
Jun 18 11:28:51 Serv kernel: [778684.508035] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 33 using
```

These will start being numbered at 1, usually stop between 100-150, will pause for about 10 seconds and then start all over again. I have made no changes to this system other than installing updates, none of which sparked any interest (apache, php, teamviewer, etc) with the exception of a kernel upgrade. I see no other errors in my logs that would be relevant. I did notice though that the mouse works only on the sidebar, but you cannot click anything on the desktop or any windowed program so I have to navigate with my keyboard. I have tried a new mouse and have the same issue. Does anyone know where I can start to look here? My syslog server is being flooded and parsing logs is nearly impossible now.

Comment: Did you try using another USB port for the mouse?

Comment: What does `uname -a` says?

Comment: Some other USB device is causing your problem. Unplug ALL USB devices except for the mouse. Reboot. Retest.

Comment: @ubfan1: Yes, I tried another port but it didnt make a difference. The messages above kept coming full speed even when it was completely unplugged.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Linux Serv 3.13.0-119-generic #166-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 3 12:18:55 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

heynnema: I am not on location right now, as soon as I get back tonight I will give that a try. There should only be one other device --an external HDD. Maybe that is it!

Comment: Alright, since as you said the problem appeared after kernel update, try installing `linux-generic-lts-xenial` which is 4.4 kernel, reboot, and check if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so this took a lot of troubleshooting, and I am not sure how this is possible but it was in fact causing the issue.

I unplugged all of the devices I could think of and the messages were coming yet. I thought guiverc may have been correct regarding a controller failure as the messages kept coming even after all USB devices were removed. This is usually a headless box and RDP wasn't playing nicely with resolution (max 640x480), so I bought an HDMI display emulator.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XT1Z9TF](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XT1Z9TF)

This device seems to have failed and somehow appeared to the server that it was a monitor which supported CEC. The server was trying to wake up the monitor repeatedly when I was using the system over RDP. I noticed that verbose logging was only happening when I was actively on the server, logs would stop about 5 minutes after I would disconnect.

My solution was to swap out the emulation device and the new one is working perfectly. I was also able to go into the BIOS and turn off CEC support which also fixed the issue, but the resolution over RDP was wonky due to the device failure.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before on two 'older' boxes, the first box had all-usbs cease working ~two months after issue started, the second was still going when I left the organization.

I'd take it as a possible sign of a failing part. Low-speed is usually keyboard or mouse; maybe an "iffy" electrical connection is causing disconnect-reconnect and resultant message, but both boxes I saw it on had the message continue with all usb devices removed.

I realize this is all CONJECTURE, but I'd take it as a sign of a possible-hardware failure coming.  (I can't comment; hence comment as answer)

- ps: I created a dirty .pl script to just delete those lines from the logs I had to watch...

Comment: I thought you were correct with a controller hardware failure of the controller, but I found the solution and have posted it below. Thank you for the advice!